# Insert dynamically a Button/PictureBox into a PictureBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dynamically-generated

I am trying to create an Image Mapper for a construction planner. When click on the construction plan I want to appear a button or a `PictureBox` inside the Image Mapper (witch is also a `PictureBox`).I have tried this code:

```
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
{
    Button b = new Button();
    int i = 0;
    b.Location = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    b.Name = "button_" + (i + 1).ToString();
    b.Text = "Click";
    b.Size = new Size(110, 42);
    b.Font = new Font("MinionPro", 20);
    b.Padding = new Padding(0);
    Controls.Add(b);
}
```

It will only work on the `Form` but not on the `PictureBox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have added this dynamically created button to your form (`Controls.Add(b);`). If you want to add it to your `PictureBox` then you need to change this:

```
Controls.Add(b);
```

To this:

```
yourPictureBox.Controls.Add(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Controls.Add(b);
```

Above line of code add your button to a Form control, not inside pictureBox

so have to add your control inside pictureBox

```
pictureBox1.Controls.Add(b);
```

this way your newly created control will be added inside picturebox

Answer (score 0):

You should make the picture box the parent of the button

```
  b.Parent = pictureBox1;
```